# Pass data to component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to pass data from one component to another, but there is some problem.
Can someone help with this? Here is my code:

```html
<template>
   <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 900px">
   <div v-if="fields.length">
      <q-item-label header>User settings</q-item-label>
      <q-list v-for="field in fields" :key="field.id">
      <div v-if="field.type == 'singleLine'">
         <q-item>
            <q-item-section>
               <s-input
                  :label="field.name"
                  :rule="field.rule"
                  :required="field.required"
                  :type="field.fieldType" />
            </q-item-section>
            <q-item-section side top>
               <div style="display: inline-flex;">
                  <div>
                     <q-icon name="edit" color="blue" size="md" @click="editField = true"/>
                     <q-tooltip>
                        Edit {{ field.name }} field
                     </q-tooltip>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </q-item-section>
         </q-item>
      </div>
      <q-dialog v-model="editField">
         <edit-field
            :field="field"
            >
         </edit-field>
      </q-dialog>
   </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'Registration',
  data() {
    return {
      newItem: true,
      titleAction: null,
      title: null,
      titleHideEvent: false,
      editField: false,
      fields: {},
      field: {},
      loading: false
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  mounted() {
    this.titleAction = 'Registration'
    this.titleHideEvent = true
  }
}
```

Edit field component:

```
<template>
  <q-card>
    <q-card-section>
      <div class="text-h6">Edit Field</div>
    </q-card-section>

    <q-separator />

    <q-card-section style="max-height: 60vh; min-width: 560px;" class="scroll">
      <q-form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <s-select
          autocomplete
          sorted
          v-model="fieldToSubmit.type"
          :options="$store.getters['options/list']('fieldTypes')"
          option-value="value"
          option-label="label"
          label="Field Type"
          required
        />
        <s-input v-model="fieldToSubmit.name" label="Name" required />
        <s-select
          autocomplete
          sorted
          v-model="fieldToSubmit.subType"
          :options="$store.getters['options/list']('registrationFieldTextSubTypes')"
          option-value="value"
          option-label="label"
          label="Subtype"
          required
        />
        <s-checkbox v-model="fieldToSubmit.required" label="Required" />
        <s-checkbox v-model="fieldToSubmit.active" label="Active" />

        <q-separator />

        <q-card-actions align="right">
          <q-btn flat label="Cancel" color="primary" v-close-popup />
          <q-btn label="Add" color="primary" type="submit" v-close-popup />
        </q-card-actions>
      </q-form>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['field'],
  data () {
    return {
      fieldToSubmit: {
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit () {
      console.log(this.fieldToSubmit)
      this.$q.notify({
        color: 'green-4',
        textColor: 'white',
        icon: 'cloud_done',
        message: 'Submitted'
      })
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.fieldToSubmit = Object.assign({}, this.field)
  }
}
</script>
```

when i click on edit button it opens modal but it doesn't fill fields with existing values.
Does anyone know what could be problem? I've tried to pass values of field with props but i don't know is this proper way to do it

Comment: Always try to supply simplified code pls. Your way of passing prop-data looks good, though you don't need Object.assign (already passing an object). Check whats actually in the field object by displaying {{ field }} somewhere in your parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the parent template's HTML is invalid:  `q-list` and the `div` before it are not properly closed.  That may be part of the problem.

You need to import and register the `edit-field` component in the parent before you can use it.  Do an `import` before the existing `export`.  Depending on file name and path, something like

```js
import edit-field from '@/components/edit-field.vue';
```

Then, also in the parent, change the options to include a `components` property for registering child components, and list the imported component there as follows:

```js
name: 'Registration',
components: {
  edit-field
},
data () {
...
```

The props usage that you mentioned looks ok, assuming `field` has data in the parent.

Comment: i have another js file for importing components, it show that form from edit-field component, but it just doesn't retrieve field data

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(this.field)` in the child's `mounted`?

Comment: That indicates that `field` is empty in the parent.  Also the `q-list` tag is not closed so your HTML is invalid.  And another `div` outside of it is also not closed.  May be related.

Comment: What happens if you fix the template tags?  If `q-dialog` is not inside `q-list`, then `field` isn't defined where you pass it to the child.

Comment: i fix all template tags and put q-dialog inside q-list but it's same problem. If i put q-dialog inside q-item it doesn't open

Comment: It just needs to be inside `q-list` because that's where you define `field`.  Do you see a field name here:  `Edit {{ field.name }} field`?  If so, there's no reason it would be undefined when passing to `edit-field`.

Comment: Also, remove `field` from the parent's data property since you are defining it in the `v-for`

Comment: everything was solved after i delete field from data property